# What is "gilhooley"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, nonce-words

Reading Ellery Queen's *The Murderer is a Fox*, I came across this passage:-

> When Fox asked me on the phone to deliver a bottle of 100 aspirins, I
>   said: "Say, Mr Fox, what do you do with that stuff - eat it?" You
>   know, cracking wise. But he gets sore and wants to know what "right" I
>   have talking to him "that way", and a lot more **gilhooley** like
>   that.

I can guess from the context what it means (something similar to *codswallop*, I'd say). But I can't find out anything about the word. Green's *Dictionary of Slang* doesn't have it, and the only definitions I can find on-line are proper names. Can anyone confirm what it means, and offer an etymology? Or is it just a nonce word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a variant on *hooey*, which the OED defines as:

> Humbug, nonsense.

It’s marked as slang that was originally from the U.S.  Also so labelled is *phooey*, which is given to mean:

> An expression of strong disagreement with or disapproval of something said. Also as sb., applied to the thing said: nonsense, ‘baloney’.

Both terms’ first citations are from the 1920s.

> 1924 P. Marks *Plastic Age* 100 — My prof’s full of hooey. He doesn’t know a C theme from an A one.
>
> 1929 *Sun* (Baltimore) 11 July 11/1 — Girls are described as weenies, janes, dames and broads. A mad-man is phooey, crackers or blooey.

Of *hooey* it says “Origin unknown”.